# how to erase the EditText fields when reverting back to the same activity ?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two Edit Fields "Username" and "Password" and everytime i revert back to this page containing these fields, the values do not get erased. I tried using the following code, but to no help :

```
            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterUsername);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterPassword);
          username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
               username.setText("");
           }

 });

    password.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
               password.setText("");
           }

 });
```

what could be done in order to erase the previous entries of the EditText fields when going back to the same activity ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Activity onResume() you do this to clear EditText data.

```
protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        password.setText("");
        username.setText("");

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why are you setting `setOnClickListener`?
 It'll be of use only is user *clicks* those fields.

Instead write following code in your `onCreate()`.
 So when you are returning back to the activity, that activity will be re-created and hence `onCreate()` will be called.

```
username.setText("");
password.setText("");
```

**Note:**

Ensure that you have initialized them before using by writing:

```
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterUsername);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterPassword);
```

Comment: Also, if i need to set the spinner to default value, how can it be done? I'm also using a drop-down list for one field. It still retains the old result.

Comment: Actually if you are coming back from an activity, it is **NOT** *re-created* but it is *re-started*. My fault, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should

```
password.setText("");
username.setText("");
```

only when some confirm/submit button is pressed and login was successful.

the

> onResume

is called even when u resume your application from a minimized state.

that would be a break to user experience when suppose i type my username,pwd and a VoiceCall comes. I attend/reject call and i'm surprised that i have to type all those things again???

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setText(null)` to your EditText in `onResume` method of your login activity